# Hide product categories where the product query returns no results

Tags: woocommerce

I'm working on a website where there are visible products (catalog) & hidden products (search). I display categories on the main shop page and subcategories are show on product category pages.

I would like to hide product subcategories that have **no** visible products (or when the product query returns no results).

Any idea?

Comment: Please do some research and show your efforts what you have done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$list_args['hide_empty'] = 1;
```

In your category listing query.

Or you can try

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item', 10, 3 );
function nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $nopost = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0" );
  foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
    if ( ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) && ( in_array( $item->object_id, $nopost ) ) ) {
        unset( $items );
    }
 }
  return $items;
}
```